# Two dictionary nested inside

Tags: python-3.x

I have nested dictionary like this:

```
dic={'dic1':'a': , 'b': , 'dic2':'a': , 'b':  , 'dic3':'a': , 'b': }
```

each inner dictionary has a many rows of data. 
There is two problem:
1. I want to compare value of 'a' in nested dictionary to the value of one of hdf5 file dataset containing two dataset `dataset1` and `dataset2` such as if values of `a` exists in `dataset1`, access to the `dataset2` values.

2.Access to the `'b'`information corresponds to `'a'` data?
for the first part I'm doing following procedure which is a never ending solution and for the second question I don't know how to access to the `b` in the the same tuple of `a`!
Does anybody have any clue how can I solve this?

```
for key, value in dict.items():
 for k,v in value.items():
     if 'a' in k:
        for t in entry[key][k]:
            if t in file['/dataset1']:
                joint = file['/dataset2'][file['/dataset1'] == t]
```

Comment: `{'a' , 'b'}` is a set, not a dictionary

Comment: Yea my mistake I will correct the question! thanks

Comment: Um, your edit made it worse. I think you meant it to be `{'a': some_iterable, 'b': some_other_object}`. What you have now is not valid Python.

Comment: because my dictionary is too large I did mistake to simplify it here. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need the second loop, if your `'a'` and '`b`' keys are always present and known in advance (if not, you could add a test `if 'a' in inner_dict and 'b' in inner_dict`). Your test `'a' in k` probably doesn't do what you expect (it's doing a substring match on an inner key string, which might give false positives if not all the keys are single characters).

Try something like this:

```
for outer_key, inner_dict in dic.items():
    for t in inner_dict['a']:
        if t in file['/dataset1']:
            joint = file['/dataset2'][file['/dataset1'] == t] # not sure this makes sense
            b_value = inner_dict['b']
            # I think you want to do something with b_value here, but I'm not sure what
```

Comment: sadly It didn't help. it still takes ages to give me an answer

Comment: Well, your question wasn't about performance, and without more information about the *actual* content of your data structure, I can't guess and what could be done to improve it. Perhaps you should work on it a bit more and then ask a new question about the performance issues?

Comment: Yes you are right I wasn't clear. I know that dictionary doesn't have index but I am wondering maybe there would be some ways to understand for which "b " values the values of "a" are equals to "dataset1" items ... the problem is in previous way it returns all the values stored in "b"

Comment: I have no idea what the types of those objects are, so there's no possible way for me to help you optimize your use of them. If you want an answer about the performance, you need to give all the relevant details. That your objects are referred to as `'a'` and `'b'` doesn't get me very far.